# Refering to columns in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes "ldf" and want to keep specific columns in each df of this list (those columns have the same name in each df)

I tried it like this which obviously failed,..

```
   newList <-
   lapply(names(ldf), function(i){
       x <- ldf[[ i ]]
       x <- x[c("Var1", "Var2")]
     })
```

Example:

```
 ldf <- list(data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5, c = 1:5), data.frame(a = 1:5, b      = 1:5, c = 1:5))
```

When only keeping Var1 and Var2 the new list should be:

```
 list(data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5), data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5))
```

Comment: Try iterating over the data frames in a list (not their names) with `foo <- list(mtcars, mtcars);lapply(foo, function(x) x[, c("mpg", "cyl")])`

Comment: This `lapply(ldf, "[", c("a", "b"))` ?

Comment: Thanks PoGibas that works! Ronak Shah your approach seems to delete the data frames completly

Comment: It returns me list of 2 dataframes with `a` and `b` columns selected in each and actually it's the same approach as @PoGibas' .